# Somar número de um arquivo txt

Tags: android

É o seguinte, estou utilizando esse método para fazer a leitura do meu arquivo txt.

```
 public String lerArquivo2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileInputStream input = context.openFileInput("teste46a.txt");
        int byteLido = 0;

        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

        while ((byteLido = input.read()) != -1) {
            str.append((char) byteLido);


        }
        System.out.print(str);
        return str.toString();
    }
```

E dentro desse txt estão os números 7.0 6.5 6.0 12.0 eu preciso somar todos esses números o resultado final teria que ser 31.5.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer desse jeito:

```
String aSeparar = lerArquivo2();

String stringNumeros[] = aSeparar().split(" ");

float total = 0f;

for(int i = 0; i < stringNumeros.length(); i++)
{

    float numero = Float.parseFloat(stringNumeros[i]);
    total += numero;

}
```